# Different rendering in mobile view and manual browser resize

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design

I have faced a weired behavior and I can not find what is the reason of this behavior. [My websites](http://www.newdesign.ir/plan3/) have two different rendering when I resize the Google Chrome manually and when I check the website in the Device simulator (using developer tools).

[image]

Brief:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
          //Entire the codes here with no overflowed element
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have no styling on the **width** of HTML and BODY tags. The direct child of body is a DIV again with **no styling on width** (So it should cover 100%). When I resize the window manully the DIV covers 100% of the width of viewport but when I resize the window in device simulator (developer tools), the child DIV is being shrinked faster than the viewport and whitespace appears in right of window.

In a real mobile device, When I check the website, the top menu Icon goes out of the width of screen and I can see the half of this icon so it seems that the rendering in the device simulator is the real logic which happens is a real device. If you zoom out then webpage in a real device, the Menu icon comes back to the screen however I have set the following and I expect that the page open in full width by default But it seems zoomed-In that I can oom out after page load):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

More checks:

- There is no calculated padding and margin in body and html when I inspect elements.
- I have removed AOS library from the webpage to make sure that the thirdparty library is not making margin and padding but no change.
- I have tested `overflow-x:0` for body to make sure there is no overflow element but no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `div` which its position is out of the width (viewport) of the website:

```html
<div style="position:absolute;left:calc(10% + 350px);top:120px;color:#f57f20;font-size:20pt;">
  <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
      with Plan
    </font>
  </font>
</div>
```

Notice the `calc(10% + 350px)`.

[image]

By the way, if you want to cut the overleft out, you can style the `html` tag (not, the `body` tag) like this:

```css
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```